# “No rule to make target `clean'. Stop.” issue

Tags: makefile, driver, ethernet

Can someone explain please where is the mistake ?
Trying to install drivers for NIC which was download from [official](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=4&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true) website and getting error:

```
[root@london r8169-6.023.02]# make clean modules
make -C src/ clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/av/r8169-6.023.02/src'
make -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/home/av/r8169-6.023.02/src clean
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64'
make[1]: *** [clean] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/av/r8169-6.023.02/src'
make: *** [clean] Error 2
[root@london r8169-6.023.02]#
```

So the manual provided by Realtek says:

> If you are running the target kernel, then you should be able to do :
>
> ```
>                 # make clean modules    (as root or with sudo)
>                 # make install
>                 # depmod -a
>                 # modprobe r8169
> ```

Makefile is:

```
KFLAG := 2$(shell uname -r | sed -ne 's/^2\.[4]\..*/4/p')x

all: clean modules install

modules:
ifeq ($(KFLAG),24x)
        $(MAKE) -C src/ -f Makefile_linux24x modules
else
        $(MAKE) -C src/ modules
endif

clean:
ifeq ($(KFLAG),24x)
        $(MAKE) -C src/ -f Makefile_linux24x clean
else
        $(MAKE) -C src/ clean
endif

install:
ifeq ($(KFLAG),24x)
        $(MAKE) -C src/ -f Makefile_linux24x install
else
        $(MAKE) -C src/ install
endif
```

Additional info

```
[root@london r8169-6.023.02]# lsmod | grep r8169
[root@london r8169-6.023.02]#
```

and directory with **Makefile**

```
[root@london r8169-6.023.02]# ls -lah
total 24K
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4.0K Sep 26 16:50 .
drwx------. 4 av   av   4.0K Nov 28 16:21 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 2.0K Oct 20 10:23 Makefile
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 4.4K Oct 20 10:23 readme
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4.0K Sep 26 16:50 src
[root@london r8169-6.023.02]#
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The makefile in `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64` doesn't have a `clean` target

Comment: Sorry ? I don't have a `Makefile` in `usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64`

Comment: Well, that's your problem then.  You can easily see what's happening from the logging you've posted here: your top-level makefile cd's into `src` and runs `make clean` there.  The makefile in `src` cd's to `/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64/build`, which could be a symlink to `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64`, and runs `make SUBDIRS=/home/av/r8169-6.023.02/src clean` there.  And since there's (as you say) no makefile there, it fails to find a `clean` rule.  Perhaps it's expecting that directory to contain an already-configured Linux kernel (so the makefile exists)?

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry..
There are only some packages need to be intalled.
type `sudo synaptic` in terminal and enter.
in search box type `qt4-qmake` and mark for installation.
then same as above search `libqt4-dev` and `libxml2-dev` and do the same mark for installation simultaneously.
then apply without check the download option.

Then go to cd netanim directory and type `make clean` and enter, 
if it does not work type `qmake NetAnim.pro` and enter, it takes couple of seconds.
then type `make` and enter.
Here its done, it will take less then a minute.
 Now in netanim directory tyoe `./NetAnim` and enter.

Here you will see animation interface.
Good luck